# Hibernate: @OneToMany: delete entity from "Many" side causes EntityNotFoundException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public static class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    String st;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
    // get,set 
}

@Entity
public static class Child {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    String st;

    @ManyToOne()
    private Parent parent;
    //get,set
  }
```

Note, that there is no Cascade on @OneToMany side.

And I want the following:

1. I have one Parent with one Child in Detached state.
2. Now I want to remove child by some condition, so I'm accesing all children, find necessary and remove it directly via em.remove(child). + I remove it from Parent's collection.
3. After that I want to change some property of Parent and save it also.
   And I'm getting EntityNotFound exception.

I performed some debug, and found that children collection is PersistentSet which remembered it's state in storedSnapshot. So, when I'm merging Parent to context - Hibernate do something with that stored snapshot and tries to load child it from DB. Of course, there is no such entity and exception is thrown.

So, there are couple of things I could do:

1. Map collection with  @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
2. During removing from children collection - cast to PersistentSet and clear it also.

But it seems like a hack.

So,
1. What I'm doing wrong? It seems, that it's correct to remove child entity directly
2. Is there more elegant way to handle this?

Reproducible example:

```
@Autowired
PrentCrud parentDao;

@Autowired
ChiildCrud childDao;
@PostConstruct
public void doSomething() {

    LogManager.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL").setLevel(Level.DEBUG);


    Parent p = new Parent();
    p.setSt("1");
    Child e = new Child();
    e.setParent(p);
    e.setSt("c");
    p.getChildren().add(e);
    Parent save = parentDao.save(p);
    e.setParent(save);
    childDao.save(e);
    Parent next = parentDao.findAll().iterator().next();
    next.setSt("2");
    next.getChildren().size();
    childDao.deleteAll();
    next.getChildren().clear();
    if (next.getChildren() instanceof PersistentSet) { // this is hack, not working without
        ((Map)((PersistentSet) next.getChildren()).getStoredSnapshot()).clear();
    }
    parentDao.save(next); // exception is thrwn here without hack
    System.out.println("Success");

}
```

Comment: Can you add a stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing fetch type to eager? defaults for relations 
    
    `OneToMany: LAZY
    ManyToOne: EAGER
    ManyToMany: LAZY
    OneToOne: EAGER`

maybe it gets cached because of fetch method

Comment: Actually, I don't want to change fetch type. I really want it to be lazy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next.setChildren(new HashSet<>());` instead of `next.getChildren().clear();` to get rid of the `getStoredSnapshot()).clear()`

But it would be more elegant to use cascade and orphanRemoval.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

public void doSomething() {
    ...
    next.setSt("2");
    next.setChildren(new HashSet<>());
    parentDao.save(next);
    System.out.println("Success");
}
```